# Rock Paper Scissors logic does not give "TIE!" even if user input is Rock and Computer input is Rock

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript">

  //Gets the computer choice

  function ComputerPlay(){
   let options= ["Rock","Paper","Scissors"]
   let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*options.length);

   return options[randomNumber].toLowerCase();
  }

  //Asks the user to type a move and returns it

  function UserPlay(){
   let userAnswer= prompt("What is your move?").toLowerCase();
   return userAnswer;
  }

  

  function PlayRound(playerSelection, computerSelection){
   let output;
   if (playerSelection===computerSelection) {
    output="TIE!"
   }
   return output;


  }

  //This is for control purpose.
  console.log(ComputerPlay());
  console.log(PlayRound(UserPlay(), ComputerPlay()));

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to understand where it goes wrong but I got no idea! It is such a simple thing and it is frustrating that I cannot find the problem.

As you can see, it is asking user to type what they choose and then it is turned into lowercase then if they match (rock===rock) then in console it should say "TIE!" but it says TIE randomly and not when it should.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The computer's option is set every time the `ComputerPlay()` is called which means that the printed value `console.log(ComputerPlay())` is different than the value compared to the user's choice.

Comment: @Titus such a mistake... Thank you I fixed by changing my code in PlayRound to:

  function PlayRound(playerSelection, computerSelection){
   let output;
   if (playerSelection===computerSelection) {
    output=`TIE! the computer answer was ${computerSelection}`
   }
   return output;

thank you. I simply did not think that it is actually called twice and of course it will print something else.